# Interleave data using Java

Tags: java, performance

```
protected static String[] applyInterleave(String interleave, int lengthOfSequence, int numOfPermutations){
    String[] interleavedPatterns = new String[numOfPermutations];
    char[] pattern = interleave.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder interleavedPattern = new StringBuilder("");

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPermutations; i++){
        char[] data = designs[i].toCharArray();
        for(int j = 0; j < lengthOfSequence; j++)
            interleavedPattern.append(data[Character.getNumericValue(pattern[j])-1]);

        interleavedPatterns[i] = interleavedPattern.toString();
        interleavedPattern = new StringBuilder("");
    }
    return interleavedPatterns;
}
```

In this code, `design` is of size `numOfPermutations` and each element in design is a string of length `lengthOfSequence`. Now, I am taking each element in `design` and applying an interleave mapping based on the parameter `interleave`.

For instance, let's say the string is `1432`. Then, I take each element in `design` and I reorder it so that the 1st char of string is still the 1st, then the 4th char becomes the 2nd, the 3rd char stays the 3rd, and the 2nd char becomes the 4th.

For example, if the first element in design, `design[0]` = `4321` and if the passed in parameter for `interleave` is `1432` then `4321` is reordered as `4123`. There are very specific reasons why I am only working with `String` instead of `int`, so I am not interested in changing the variable types.

Now, if my design array is really large, say `362880` indices long, then this method takes quite a while. I have optimized to the best of my ability, but is there a way to speed this up even more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Optimization 1

Instead of constantly doing `Character.getNumericValue(pattern[j])-1` in the inner loop, you could create a precomputed integer array to hold those values.  That way, you could replace that expression with `patIndex[j]`.

#### Optimization 2

Instead of using multiple instances of `StringBuilder`, you could use and reuse a single char array and create strings from that.

#### Optimization 3

Instead of creating a char array from your `designs[i]` string, you could just leave `designs[i]` as a string and use `String.charAt()` to read each character.

#### Sample rewrite

Using the above 3 optimizations, I arrived at:

```
static String[] applyInterleave(String interleave, int lengthOfSequence,
        int numOfPermutations)
{
    String[] interleavedPatterns = new String[numOfPermutations];
    char  [] pattern  = interleave.toCharArray();
    int   [] patIndex = new int[lengthOfSequence];

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfSequence; i++) {
        patIndex[i] = Character.getNumericValue(pattern[i])-1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPermutations; i++) {
        String s = designs[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < lengthOfSequence; j++) {
            pattern[j] = s.charAt(patIndex[j]);
        }
        interleavedPatterns[i] = new String(pattern);
    }
    return interleavedPatterns;
}
```

I tested this against the original function and found that it was approximately 3x faster.